# My Project Couldn't be run Windows 10 IOT

Tags: c#, powershell, uwp

I'm creating apps by VS 2015.

My Project is made by UWP. I know this is for Windows Store Apps.

however, My Project is LOB Side Loading.

I compiled and packaged my project, and then I moved to all of files to other computer.

then,

1. I Set '**Developer mode**' in Control Panel.
2. I executed '**Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned**' in PowerShell.
3. then i excuted '**Add-AppDevPackage.ps1**', then my app installed successfully.

However, I found my app in start menu, but I couldn't click that !!

I couldn't launch that.

How can I do to launch my uwp app in other computer?

Comment: "in other computer" you mean [Windows 10 IoT Core device](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/getstarted/prototype/selectdevice)?

Comment: Yes, OS is Win 10 IoT Enterprise.

Comment: Reboot after Install, i could click my app in start menu,

Comment: but without reboot, i couldn't click my app in start menu..

Comment: however the mystery is, 'new apps' or 'favorite apps' menu (sorry, because i'm not using english version OS, i don't know whether this is a proper terms), i could click them without reboot.

Comment: Have you tried the simplest app like "hello world"? And which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: now, i tried simplest app, then it could be clicked at start menu. however, the app couldn't be clicked also could be clicked. i watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUkwHSYyZic

Comment: I followed the youtube link you provided and create a "hello world" app. Install the app on another Windows 10 desktop and I can click it at the start menu and it runs successfully. But I don't have an enterprise device to test. Have you test on other desktop devices?

Comment: I haven't tested other desktop devices, but my project is only for enterprise version device.

Comment: So, can you launch the simplest app?